# mysqli query to update rank column of students on go

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I have this sql table for the student database.
[image]
The PHP script is used to count the votes. 
I have this query used to rank the students. 
This SELECT Query works perfectly but I want to **update** the column as per the no on votes.

```
SELECT id, first, vote, @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank
FROM student_table p, (
SELECT @curRank := 0
) q
ORDER BY vote DESC
```

**update**:
ty guys this worked for me :)

```
mysqli_query($conn, 'UPDATE student_table SET rank= @r:=0 ORDER BY vote DESC');
mysqli_query($conn, 'UPDATE student_table SET rank= @r:=(@r+1) ORDER BY vote DESC');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SET @r=0;
UPDATE student_table SET rank= @r:= (@r+1) ORDER BY vote DESC;
```

Comment: the above query gave an error so i used this way... UPDATE student_table SET rank= @curRank:= @curRank+1 ORDER BY vote DESC; this query gives no error but the column is not updated the values are still zero

Comment: It worked for me as I have created same table structure as you have and tried........what error you got ?

Comment: awesome it worked in phpmyadmin but still not working in the php mysqli_query

Comment: Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Sql Query:

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM tablename ORDER BY vote DESC";

check condition if(q->num_rows > 0){
$rank = 1;
then while loop($row = $q->fetch_assoc()) {
$id = $row['id'];
//update rank column
$q1 = "UPDATE tablename SET rank='".$rank"' WHERE id='".$id."' "
$rank++;
}

}//if close
```

Comment: this does not work, i just want an sql query like in the question to update the column.

Answer (score 0):

Below is an alternate update query without using variables in MySQL.

```
update test
inner join (select id,name,vote,(select count(id) + 1 
                                 from test where id != t.id and vote > t.vote) as 'rank'
            from test t) derived_test
ON test.id = derived_test.id
set test.rank = derived_test.rank;
```

You can look at this [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2d7c0/2) to understand how ranks are being assigned.

Comment: alternate ways always help :)

Comment: @MarkPatel if this helped you in some way, can you consider upvoting it?